# Word for a precious memory

Tags: single-word-requests

We all have them.  Experiences we will never forget.  Fond moments we will forever cherish.

But I was surprised I could not think of any word to describe such a valuable thing.

Is there any word that means *a precious memory*?

Comment: The German language seems fond of joining two or more words together to make a new word which expresses a single idea, like this.  This phenomenon isn't as common in English.  I don't believe this exists: people would just say "precious memories".

Comment: Only answers you'll probably get are synonyms of those two words mixed and matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it a **treasure** or **a treasured memory**.

[Defined by Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treasure) as

> (verb) to hold or keep as precious.
>
> (noun) something that is very special, important, or valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you are going to do is the word **reminiscence**.

A reminiscence *could* be pleasant and precious, though not necessarily. In its favor is that the person who is reminiscing is *choosing* to remember something precious, whereas a person with an unpleasant memory might choose to suppress or repress it (though I'm sure there are people who hold onto bad memories and re-live them, so to speak, again and again masochistically).

Not in its favor is that reminiscence is often accompanied by a descriptor. Some examples:

> - a pleasant reminiscence
> - a nostalgic reminiscence
> - my favorite reminiscence
> - a shared reminiscence